# How do I list all the created (added) files in all the commits from a particular date?

Tags: git

I need to list only newly added files in all the commits from a particular date.

For example: I have many git commits and I have to list all the created/added files in all the commits from October 1 2019.

Comment: `git log` has `--since` and `--until` (with various alternative spellings) to select commits within a date range. And, `git log` has options to show a diff from parent to child, with some of those options limiting the diff to file names and optional status codes. And, one of the status codes is `A`: an added file. So just use `git log` with the appropriate options.

Comment: If this is a one off and not for scripting, and you just want to see the files that are in the current `main` vs those in a particular commit, `git diff --stat old_sha1 main` is quite concise and includes the info you want. Better yet, `--name-status` will print just the file names with `A` in front of added files: `git diff --name-status old_sha1 main | grep ^A`

Answer (score 3):

The `--name-status` switch to either `git log` or `git diff` will show changes with a one-letter status code: `A` for added, `M` for modified, etc.

You can combine that with `--diff-filter A` to ask Git to only show you added files.

If you know the old commit you want to compare to main, you can use:

```
git diff --name-status --diff-filter A old_sha1 main
```

As @torek said, you can also use `git log` with `--since` to pick a date. The same `--name-status` will make it easy to extract just the added files:

```
git log --since 2019-10-01 --name-status --diff-filter A
```

With `git diff`, if the file was later removed, you will not see it, whereas with `git log`, you will.

**Edit**: replaced my grep with the proper `--diff-filter` switch.

**PS**: the key here is really the `--diff-filter A` option, once you have that, pick any output format you want, like `--name-only`, `--stat`, or whatever.

Comment: This solution seems to work but it is not giving me the commits from the specified date and there are commits for the date in the repo.

Comment: @Ranjeet tell us more about the commits that get missed. Are they on a different branch, or is there something wonky about them? Or maybe they're on the date you specify in your time zone but not in UTC (or vice versa)? If you can't figure it out, it might be worth asking a separate question about how to get `--since` to do what you want.

Comment: If the missing commits you want to see are merge commits, maybe you want to add `--diff-merges on`?